# How to use the UndistortPoints function in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#define fx 1532.49;
#define fy 1521.439;
#define cx 1267.78;
#define cy 952.078;

Mat_<float> cam(3,3); cam << 1531.49,0,1267.78,0,1521.439,952.078,0,0,1;
Mat_<float> dist(1,5); dist <<-0.27149,0.15384,0.0046,-0.0026;

const int npoints = 2; // number of point specified 

// Points initialization. 
// Only 2 ponts in this example, in real code they are read from file.
Mat_<Point2f> points(1,npoints);
points(0) = Point2f(0,0);
points(1) = Point2f(2560, 1920);

Mat dst;// leave empty, opencv will fill it.
undistortPoints(points, dst, cam, dist);
MatIterator_<double> i;
 for(i=dst.begin<double>();i!=dst.end <double>();++i)
  {

      cout<<(*i)<<endl;
  }
```

I want to use UndistortPoints function to remove  distortion.
This is the UndistortPoints function in OpenCV2.4.9 with vs2012,But when it run,it only output 2 parameter.what' s wrong?Can anyone help me ? thank you.

Here is the result!Here is the result!run the code[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INMoa.jpg).

Comment: Has been a while, but I think if there are two points, and your for condition is `i!=dest.end<double>()`, will not the code skip the last point of your points list?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are 4 four values in `Mat dst`, whose value type is `float` (`FLOAT32`) instead of `double`.

You can simply `cout` the entire matrix to see it clearly:

```
cout << dst;
```

Comment: Thank you .I have change the  data structure,from Mat_ to Mat(its type is CV_64FC,not the CV_32FC)  and it done。